# Trouble pressing button using CALayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a button (iOS) that has the mask set for its CALayer:

```
self.aButton.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

then later the bounds are defined much smaller than the button area (button size about 50x50pts).

```
button.layer.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 29, 29);
```

Now the button can only be clicked on inside the layer area. What is the simplest way to allow the entire button area (50x50pts) to still be clickable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mask the layer of a UIView, add it as a subview to the button.

```
UIView *redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 29, 29)];
redView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];

redView.center = aButton.center;
redView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[aButton addSubview:redView];
```

---

Or as a sublayer

```
CALayer *layer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
layer.frame = CGRectMake(10.5, 10.5, 29, 29);

UIButton *aButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[aButton.layer addSublayer:layer];
```